# FreeImage zero width and height

Tags: c++, freeimage

I'm trying to load a `.png` and a `.DDS` file in FreeImage, but the width and height are always zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <FreeImage.h>

int main(void){
  const char* path = "Signal.png";
  printf("Loading image %s\n", path);
  FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_Load(FreeImage_GetFileType(path), path, 0);
  unsigned int w = FreeImage_GetWidth(image);
  unsigned int h = FreeImage_GetHeight(image);
  printf("Width: %u Height: %u\n", w, h);

}
```

Output:

```
Loading image Signal.png
Width: 0 Height: 0
```

Comment: See docs for `FreeImage_SetOutputMessage` and use it, maybe you will get an error message. Also you might be missing a call to `FreeImage_Initialise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing a call to `FreeImage_Initialise` (unless you are using a DLL).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes freeimage doesntmanage to read the FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT from FreeImage_GetFileType

so it is recomended to check the validity of fif and if fif == FIF_UNKNOWN  use FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename